# Will a concrete roof hold the weight of a roof garden?

Tags: roof, load-bearing, slab, gardening, load

We are planning to build a roof garden on a flat roof. The area of the roof is 25' x 25'. The concrete slab thickness is 6", and our structural engineer has provided sufficient reinforcements, as we had planned for this right from the beginning.

Before proceeding, we want to be doubly sure the roof will hold the weight, considering we will be adding a glass roof of approx. 7720 lbs (3500 kg)(including MS structure and glass weight). Add to this the weight of concrete planters, moist soil and plants (we have not calculated these), we are wondering whether a roof garden is a good idea at all...

Additional info - If we are going for a roof garden, a glass-roof for the garden is non-negotiable as we want to harvest rainwater and have invested in a large RWH sump underground.

Given the specifications, how much lbs /sqft can our roof hold? [image: Picture shows the columns]

Comment: Please match your units ie kgs and m^2 or pounds and square feet. If your engineer calculated the roof as you say then it should be fine. BUT did the builder make it to specification ie what about the quality of the concrete...

Comment: Thank you. Have corrected the units. However, In India, we do tend to use feet and inches a lot in distance measurements, esp. in civil work. Quite strange, now that I consider it - neither fully metric nor imperial...

The build work was supervised, so most specifications have been met, but a knowledge of total lbs /sqft will put our minds at ease...

Comment: You said, "our structural engineer has provided sufficient reinforcements, as we had planned for this right from the beginning". If your new roof-top garden is _within_ the specs that the SE used when designing the roof & support, then why _wouldn't_ your roof support what you're doing? If you're now planning _additional_ "things" on top of the roof, over & above what was originally spec'd, then you should probably go back to your SE (or a different one) to have some new calculations done.

Comment: @Geetha Raman  Canada is about the same way.  We mix and match metric and imperial.  Mainly us old folks who learnt imperial first.  Think we do it just to confuse Americans more.

Comment: @ crip659 :) @FreeMan - Had shown the added things to the SE, and he had confirmed we can go ahead. Probably it's just us, and this is not an issue at all. Just wanted to know the level of safety we have, so we are not constantly worrying about it in the future...

Comment: Please write that up as an answer, then in a few hours, when the system will let you, click the check mark next to your answer. That will let others know that this has been resolved.

Comment: It seems like you should go back to your SE if you have any questions about their work. Surely they'll know how much weight they planned for.

Comment: *"our structural engineer"* would be the person to ask who knows precisely. If you changed the loading after the roof was designed to hold one set of things but not another, only your engineer, or another engineer who will have to incur more expense re-creating the work of your engineer will know if there is enough margin in the design to allow for the additional load, or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Will go back to the SE and get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A structural engineer is required to go over your plan and to get the permit for the glass roof addition. Your roof was not designed to support the additional dead weight and wind load on the glass roof.

Answer (score 2):

You didn’t mention the type of concrete structural system used for your roof, (i.e.; flat slab, concrete joists with slab above, waffle slab, etc.)

Without knowing the exact specifications on the grade of concrete, size and spacing of the reinforcement, it would be difficult to determine the maximum load allowed. However, concrete is a great material to give you “hints” as to its condition before total failure.

Seldom are structural systems loaded to their ultimate load. That is because there is a safety factor calculated into the design. Often this safety factor is 1.6, or even 2.5. Which means when you add all the live and dead loads together (and often a designer will add a miscellaneous load of 10% because we know tenants will add hot tubs, etc. without asking permission) the roof will support substantially more before failure. Structural calculations are designed to show concrete failure in tension long before compression. This is to allow inspectors to see cracks on the bottom of the beams, slabs, etc. before total failure...rather than compression failure where the system goes in a bang- instantly.

If you proceed, I’d check to see if there are cracks. Just one crack is a sign and I would not proceed. However cracks where your roof system meet the walls is probably acceptable, but  I’d mark them in a journal and monitor them once a month showing crack length and width during construction.

The odd thing about concrete roof structural systems is you cannot improve its capabilities by retrofitting the system. That is to say, you can’t add interior supports at mid span to help reduce the span. This is because reinforcement is placed primarily for tension loads and that all changes when the roof system passes over a support. (That why trussed rebar is often used.)

If your SE says it’s ok, I’d trust him/her and ask for a “stamped” drawing.